# Shake a cloth out(is it used in AmE)

Tags: word-usage

Is "shake a cloth out" used in AmE? Like:

He shook out his clothes. 
He shook out the rug.

Comment: This is just English. Have you looked it up?

Comment: Yes, this is standard.  It's not even really an idiom, more of a phrasal verb.

Comment: If you include the preposition in *shake [some material, "fabric" product, etc.] **out***, this normally implies ***removing** [dust, creases, etc.]* from the thing - otherwise you'd just ***shake*** it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your examples are frequently used, although "shake a cloth out" isn't idiomatic. Generally, if you can pick up an object and something (dirt, trash, liquid spill, whatever) comes out when it's held in the air and shaken, you can use the "shake a/an/the [object] out" form.

> 1. He shook the dirt out of his backpack.
> 2. It took a while to shake out the dirt-covered clothes.
> 3. She spent some time shaking the rugs out on the balcony.

There are three different forms of this idiom as further examples.